# how to line plot values column vs groups

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe  x2 with two columns. i am trying to plot but didnt get xticks.
data:

```
       bins       pp
0     (0, 1]  0.155463
1     (1, 2]  1.528947
2     (2, 3]  2.436064
3     (3, 4]  3.507811
4     (4, 5]  4.377849
5     (5, 6]  5.538044
6     (6, 7]  6.577340
7     (7, 8]  7.510983
8     (8, 9]  8.520378
9    (9, 10]  9.721899
```

i tried this code result is fine just cant find x-axis ticks just blank. i want bins column value should be on x-axis

```
x2.plot(x='bins',y=['pp'])

x2.dtypes
Out[141]: 
bins          category
pp             float64
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine on my side

Comment: @WeNYoBen  i added my result graph , here is no value

Comment: There was a bug in pandas, which should by now be fixed. Can you try with the newest pandas version?

Comment: That is wired :-(

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest i have latest version of pandas .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is to show that this problem should not occur with pandas 0.24.1 or higher.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)    # prints 0.24.2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({"Age" : np.random.rayleigh(30, size=300)})

s = pd.cut(df["Age"], bins=np.arange(0,91,10)).value_counts().to_frame().sort_index().reset_index()

s.plot(x='index',y="Age")

plt.show()
```

results in

[image]